# how config vue.js as template engine in express (typescript) app

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, vue.js

I initialized a node app by using express.js (typescript).

Is there a way to use vue.js as template engine without using webpack?

So basically I want “MEVNT” stands for “MongoDB Express.js VueJS Node.js Typescript”.

or in another word express mvc app which uses vue js as template engine.

Comment: See "direct script include" on https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html.

Comment: Using something like Vue as the "templating language" from the server is a concept known as server-side rendering. Vue supports this and you can [read more about it here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html).